# How to store array values in new array?

Tags: php

I have this array

```
$array=(
   Array([0] => ENG)
   Array([0] => ENG)
   Array([0] => URDU)
   Array([0] => LIB)
   Array([0] => URD)
   Array([0] => ISL)
   Array([0] => PHY)
   Array([0] => ISL)
   Array([0] => SCI)
   Array([0] => MATH)
   Array([0] => CHEM)
);
```

I want to get these values and store in new array like this

```
array(
[0]=>ENG 
[1]=>ENG 
[2]=>URDU 
[3]=>LIB 
[4]=>URD 
[5]=>ISL 
[6]=>PHY
[7]=>ISL 
[8]=>SCI 
[9]MATH 
[10]=>CHEM)
```

I have tried the following

$newarray=array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) { $newarray[]=$value; }

But the result is same as i have first array

```
$array=(
   Array([0] => ENG)
   Array([0] => ENG)
   Array([0] => URDU)
   Array([0] => LIB)
   Array([0] => URD)
   Array([0] => ISL)
   Array([0] => PHY)
   Array([0] => ISL)
   Array([0] => SCI)
   Array([0] => MATH)
   Array([0] => CHEM)
);
```

Comment: Please indent and format your question properly. No one will read this debug output.

Comment: comment now on question condition

Comment: @abidali still not right format -> use linebreaks and indent

Comment: and use code formatting

Comment: @schlicki check now and suggest please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [[0=>'ENG'],[0=>'IND'],[0=>'PAK'],[0=>'ING']];

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Above code you mention is not useful. I made an array and flattened.

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ENG
    [1] => IND
    [2] => PAK
    [3] => ING
)
```

Comment: my array is displaying error 
( ! ) Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in E:\wamp64\www\timetable\controller\home.php on line 219

Comment: but how i add comma Bro solution please

Comment: $array=array();  
foreach ($subj_id as $key => $value) {
    $sql="SELECT sub_name FROM `subjects` WHERE `sub_id`='$value'";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_NUM)) { 
    foreach ($line as $col_value) { 
       $array[]=$col_value;
     } 
       $result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
echo "<pre>"; 
print`_r($result);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
{ 
    $newarray[] = $value[0];
}
```